# How do I retrieve a reproduced pdf document with php that doesn't have a file path?

Tags: php, pdf, curl, web-scraping

This is one of the most stumped I've ever been, and it's possible there is no programatic solution.

I'm scraping a municipal website for judgment liens. The resulting page has two frames, a left frame and a right frame. The left frame html is straight forward, and not the problem. The right frame produces a pdf document that corresponds to the case # found in the left hand frame.

Here's a [sample link](https://officialrecords.broward.org/oncoreV2/ShowDetails.aspx?id=47386935&direct=1) to an actual case page. Note that I've already taken care of a virtual click to agree to the TOS, so my scrape gets an actual case page rather than the T.O.S. page.

To get the page content requires two separate scrapes, where I send a TOS agreement using cURL, and I won't bore you with the code sample for that.

Immediately following the first cURL, I send the second cURL to get the content, which works fairly successfully:

```
function getHtml($url, $post = null) {
    $content = "";
    $string = "Authenticated=0&amp;AccessLevel=z58jgxoXvjk=&amp;AgentKey=&amp;CacheKey=25735097.0777&amp;LastUrl=".urlencode($url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$string");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    if(!empty($post)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    } 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

I've resolved the two frame urls in the resulting page, so it does me no good to cURL the base page, because that results in an Object Not Found error (because it's a frame page).

I call the left frame with:

```
$leftframeurl = "https://officialrecords.broward.org/oncoreV2/details.aspx?id=47386935";
$leftframecontent = getHtml($leftframeurl);
echo $leftframecontent . "<br><br>";
```

...and if I do that, I get a content that I can parse the html using simple_html_dom.

But there is a pdf scanned document that relates to this case, and that appears in the right hand frame, which you can see if you do this search by hand, using your browser.

The url to the right hand frame actually does a redirect from:

https://officialrecords.broward.org/oncoreV2/ImageBrowser/ShowPDF.aspx

to:

https://officialrecords.broward.org/oncoreV2/ImageBrowser/SinglePagePdf.aspx

where that last url is the url of the pdf. You can see there is no query string variable in either url, no "id=47386935", and no "47386935.pdf" file location anywhere. There's is nothing to reference the specific pdf at all. It seems likely to me that the pdf is being queried at the back end, out of my reach.

But what I want is to somehow access the pdf for that case.

I have also tried a separate cURL, sending pdf headers like this:

```
function getPDF($id,$url){
    $content = "";
    $string = "Authenticated=0&amp;AccessLevel=z58jgxoXvjk=&amp;AgentKey=&amp;CacheKey=25735097.0777&amp;LastUrl=".urlencode($url);
    $request = "";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_COOKIE => "$string",
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('Cache-Control: public', 'Content-type: application/pdf'),
        CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => FALSE
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$content = getPDF('47386935','https://officialrecords.broward.org/oncoreV2/ImageBrowser/SinglePagePdf.aspx');
```

...but that's not showing me any love, either.

Comment: check EVERYTHING your browser sends when you hit the page normally. that pdf script could be checking referers, maybe there's a cookie. **SOMETHING** has to be sent at some point to identify which pdf it should be outputting.

Comment: @MarcB the referrer is no help, but...wait a sec...there is a different cookie here...reporting back in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from Javascript code that calls `ImageBrowser/default.aspx?id=47386935&dtk=FJ`.

```
<script language="javascript">
parent.doc.location.href="ImageBrowser/default.aspx?id=47386935&dtk=FJ"
</script>
```

This receives the document ID in the URL, which then sets some cookies and that URL then opens ShowPDF.aspx which uses the values in the cookie to serve the appropriate PDF.

So, extract that ImageBrowser URL, call it with cURL so the appropriate cookies get set, then fetch ShowPDF.aspx and it should have the content you're looking for.

```
view-source:https://officialrecords.broward.org/oncoreV2/ImageBrowser/default.aspx?id=47386935&dtk=FJ
```

Comment: Looks promising, very excited about trying this solution. That url definitely caused the browser to redirect to the second url, and outputted the pdf in my browser. Now if I can only replicate the action using cURL.

Comment: I know how to send cookies in cURL, but I've never treid getting cookies using cURL.

Comment: Just set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to an empty string, and re-use the same curl handle for all your requests (which is good practice anyway) and it'll handle all the cookies for you automatically, and re-use existing connections so it'll be faster.

Comment: I just noticed that during the last cURL, where I'm curling the PDF page, the browser jumps to an intermediate state for a split second, and if I stop it the page title (on the browser tab) says "PDF.js viewer. I can't get much more information, and if I stop the redirect at that point, I can't even get any source code. I think my inability to get to the pdf has something to do with this PDF.js viewer transition.